# Action bar display based on fragment displayed

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am creating an app with Facebook login feature. The main screen has two fragments which show up based on the login status. If you are not logged in, a home screen with a login button shows up, which has no Action Bar. If the user is logged in, Main Activity shows the welcome page, which has the action bar. I know that to hide action bar in an activity we can add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"` to that particular activity. But i do not want the ActionBar to disappear for the entire activity as I have to show it on the other fragment.

My question is: how do I show the action bar when the user is in logged in state, and the welcome screen fragment is shown?

Here is my code in the login fragment where I do not want the action bar:

```
    public class LoginFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, 
            container, false);
    //getActivity().getActionBar().hide();

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
}   
}
```

The code for the Welcome Fragment where I want the Action BAr is as shown:

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends Fragment{

private static final String TAG = "WelcomeFragment";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome, 
            container, false);
    //getActivity().getActionBar().show();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().getActionBar().show();
}   

}
```

Comment: I have tried calling getActivity().getActionBar.show() and getActivity().getActionBar.hide() from the respective fragments. But this does not work either. I see the Action bar in both the fragments.

Answer (score 1):

you can hide and show action bar

```
  getSupportActionBar().hide();

  getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: I am not sure how this is helpful here. Can you explain properly. I am not able to use those functions from the fragments.

Comment: you can use getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide(); like this

Comment: I am not extending ActionBarActivity. So I am not able to get that option.

Comment: what you are extending fragmentactivity ?

Comment: Yes I am extending fragment activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {           
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
((YourActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting code only answers. No matter how 'simple' it may be, everything should contain some explanation.